# Given force as function of position, find the total energy as function of time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, spring, non-linear-systems

> Given that the force for a non-linear spring connected to a mass $m$ sitting on a table is $$f(x) = -kx -ax^3,$$ Find the total energy as a function of time $E(t)$.

I have no clue where to begin.

Comment: Hi Tomas and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
Use

$$m\ddot{x}=-kx-x^3 \\\ddot{x}=v\frac{dv}{dx} \\-\frac{kx^2}{2}-\frac{ax^4}{4}=\frac{m}{2}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2$$

It will reduce to a form

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=ix\sqrt{c^2+x^2}$$

This is a standard integral, and can be solved, then use

$$U=-\int f(x) dx \\T=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2$$

Total energy  $E=T+U\; .$

Comment: So I don't need to find the potential as function of time?

Comment: you have to, $x$ is a function of time. find $x$ as a function of time, and substitute it after finding $U$

Answer (score 0):

The total energy as a function of time is a constant and it is always equal to the potential energy in the point where $x=x_{max}$ and $v = 0$.

The total energy is the work done to bring the free end of the spring from $0$  to $x_{max}$.

So

$E(t) = E = Work = kx_{max}^2/2 + ax_{max}^4/4$

You simply integrate $f(x)$ from $0$ to $x_{max}$